# How can I measure the amount of CO2 in grams in a known volume of soda based on its weight?

Tags: aqueous-solution

We have a soda machine that can fill either still water or soda. In both cases the amount is 400 ml in the beaker, but the soda weighs a little less.

How can we use the volume X = 400 ml and the weight Y = ?? grams to determine the amount of $\ce{CO2}$ in the solution?

Comment: You can't. The soda likely already contains a few bubbles when it is measured into the beaker, so its average density will be less. The density difference due to dissolved $\ce{CO_2}$ is minute, i doubt you will be able to make a sample that is so exactly 400ml that your weight measurements make any sense.

Comment: Btw.: I'm sure the density of dilute carbonic acid is actually higher than distilled water. That's true for practically all kinds of solutions: If the density would sink upon dissolving, it wouldn't.

Comment: Great :) Why didnt you put that in an answer?

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily a homework question.

Comment: Actually rhis is work related. We are developing a soda dispenser.